# Spring Data REST: Disallow create POST method but allow update methods PUT/PATCH

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have a rest repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(..)
public interface RestEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String> {

}
```

There I want to disable create method. I know that it's possible with `@RestResource(exporeted = false)` annotation.
We have two types of methods `save` and `insert`, but as I understood `insert`  internally uses `save`. But if I put it for all methods `save/insert`, update doesn't work, if I put only for `insert` methods create still works.

Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar discussion within team and ended up extending SimpleMongoRepository.

```
public class MyGenericMongoRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements   MyGenericMongoRepository<T, ID> {}
```

We had plenty of reasons to do so. Custom batch sizing etc.

Comment: You mean that with SimpleMongoRepository I can disallow create but allow update?

Comment: Yes. Override save method and just do nothing.

        @Override
 public <S extends T> void save(S entity, String collectionName) {

  //do nothing
 }

Comment: Probably you didn't understand my problem